# Backup table to xml or csv file, content is long text

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a table that contains content (like blog posts, so fairly long text) that I want to export to a xml file.

So I want it like:

```
<table>
  <column1>1231</column1>
  <column2>January 1, 2001</column2>
  <column3>some very long text will all types of characters in it</column3>
</table>
```

Is there a built in way to do this?

Basically each column will have its own element.

The content should ideally be CDATA since the content can contain any type of character potentially.

I have sql server 2008 express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SQL Server 2005, the [FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188273.aspx) clause provides a way to convert the results of an SQL query to XML.

E.g.
Consider a table building with Blgd, Suit, SQFT, PDate columns.

```
SELECT * FROM building FOR XML AUTO
```

will convert the contents of table to the following XML:

```
<building Bldg="1" SUit="1" SQFT="1000" PDate="2012-09-24T00:00:00" />
<building Bldg="1" SUit="1" SQFT="1500" PDate="2011-12-31T00:00:00" />
```

If you want the columns to be elements, then

```
SELECT * FROM building FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```

would convert the contents to following XML:

```
<building>
  <Bldg>1</Bldg>
  <SUit>1</SUit>
  <SQFT>1000</SQFT>
  <PDate>2012-09-24T00:00:00</PDate>
</building>
<building>
  <Bldg>1</Bldg>
  <SUit>1</SUit>
  <SQFT>1500</SQFT>
  <PDate>2011-12-31T00:00:00</PDate>
</building>
```

If you want to model your text fields as `CDATA` sections, then you should use the `FOR XML EXPLICIT` clause and define your XML schema as per the [guidelines here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189068.aspx).

If the above Building table has a text_col column of type `TEXT` that should be modeled as CDATA section in the generated XML, then the `SELECT` query would be as follows:

```
SELECT 
    1 as Tag,
    NULL as Parent,
    Bldg AS [Building!1!Bldg!ELEMENT],
    text_col AS [Building!1!!CDATA]
FROM Building 
WHERE text_col IS NOT NULL
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

The results would be as follows:

```
<Building><Bldg>1</Bldg><![CDATA[From SQL Server 2005, the FOR XML clause provides a way to convert the results of an SQL query to XML.

E.g. Consider a table building with Blgd, Suit, SQFT, PDate columns.

SELECT * FROM building FOR XML AUTO

will convert the contents of table to the following XML:

<building Bldg="1" SUit="1" SQFT="1000" PDate="2012-09-24T00:00:00" />
<building Bldg="1" SUit="1" SQFT="1500" PDate="2011-12-31T00:00:00" />
If you want the columns to be elements, then

SELECT * FROM building FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
would convert the contents to following XML:

<building>
  <Bldg>1</Bldg>
  <SUit>1</SUit>
  <SQFT>1000</SQFT>
  <PDate>2012-09-24T00:00:00</PDate>
</building>
<building>
  <Bldg>1</Bldg>
  <SUit>1</SUit>
  <SQFT>1500</SQFT>
  <PDate>2011-12-31T00:00:00</PDate>
</building>]]></Building>
```

Comment: What about CDATA as the content could contain funny characters etc., and saving to a file?

Comment: Please see the edit about using `FOR XML EXPLICIT` to generate CDATA sections in the target XML.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FOR XML` SQL construct to do this. Please read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx)

Comment: what about saving it to a file?